# Low voltage control of 75V piezo actuator

Tags: operational-amplifier, raspberry-pi, power-electronics, high-voltage, piezo

I am looking to perform position control on a 75V piezo linear actuator with a Raspberry pi.

To do so I intend to use a 5V output DAC and some kind of power amplifier to amplify the range between 0V and 75V. For precise positioning the output voltage of the amplifier has to be stable. I have been looking at op amps for power applications but I am not sure that the previous statement will be met.

Am I not aware of some chip that would be useful in my project? Or an op amp will do the job?

Comment: You need special op amps designed for output voltages up to 75 V. Of course you need a power supply with more than 75 V.

Comment: Have you got a question to ask?

Comment: I am looking for insights on what path I should follow for controlling (not just switching on/off) high voltage with low voltage devices. I am thinking of using a DAC to control an analog signal between 0 and 5V from the pi. In order to amplify that range, I am thinking of using a high voltage op amp. My concerns are: is there a chip that will do what I am describing, with better precision than the DAC/op-amp combination? If not, where do I need to be careful when using high voltage op amp for such a design?

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways I can see doing this.

1. Start with an adjustable switching regulator (probably a boost regulator), then modify it so that it can be controlled by your PI. For example, you may be able to do something as simple as replace a potentiometer with a digital potentiometer. You also may be able to find a supply that can be digitally controlled.
2. Basically do the same thing except design the whole thing yourself. Design a boost converter, then either find the voltage reference and replace that with a DAC, or do the digital potentiometer thing.

Edit: Ok since nobody else has answered, here are some more complicated, higher speed options.

3. Use a DAC and a high voltage op amp like the [OPA445AUG4](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/OPA445AUG4/296-36127-5-ND/1572749). Use a resistor to limit the current into the piezo element.
4. To get even faster you will need to increase the current into the piezo. I would do this by buffering the op-amp with mosfets or BJTs, like this:
   [image]
   If you use mosfets, try to get ones with a small gate charge. Since that will be the limiting factor on your speed.

Comment: While practical, this approach falls apart if you need a high speed response (above a few hertz).

Comment: While the idea of using a switching rather than linear amplifier design seems worth contemplating, I doubt that typical boost regulator circuits are going to be appropriate to this.